# I see my POST data in php://input but $_POST is empty (possibly server config issue)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I have an ajax web gallery that requests folders/file paths over POST. It has been running on my xp lighttpd/php test server for a while without problems.

Yesterday i tried to move it over to my new linux dev server and decided to try using the php builtin server for the job to save me the trouble of confin apache or nginx.

**Problem is, on the new server the gallery doesnt work (and neither does it on my production host server or my old test server running php -S 0.0.0.0:80 instead of lighttpd with exactly the same php.ini that worked before) and i have narrowed it down to this: $_POST is suddenly completely empty even though i can see the posted data in php://input.**

Here is the contents of $_SERVER (running off the new linux server)

```
'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/xxx/public_html',
'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'x.x.x.x',
'REMOTE_PORT' => '54061',
'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'PHP 5.4.4-10 Development Server',
'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
'SERVER_NAME' => '0.0.0.0',
'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
'REQUEST_URI' => '/gustaf/photos/index.php',
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/gustaf/photos/index.php',
'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/xxx/public_html/gustaf/photos/index.php',
'PHP_SELF' => '/gustaf/photos/index.php',
'HTTP_HOST' => 'xxx.xxx',
'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive',
'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH' => '46',
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0',
'HTTP_ORIGIN' => 'http://xxx.xxx',
'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11',
'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'HTTP_ACCEPT' => '*/*',
'HTTP_REFERER' => 'http://xxx.xxx/gustaf/photos/index.php',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET' => 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1356462787.3962,
'REQUEST_TIME' => 1356462787,
```

This is what the JS bit looks like that shoots off the POST:

```
    xmlhttp.open("POST","index.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parent.path.length);
    //xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
    xmlhttp.send("json="+JSON.stringify({"dir":parent.path}));
```

I tried setting connection to "close" aswell, but for some reason chrome doesnt respect that and still sends it as "keep-alive".

Ive spent a whole (christmas) day on this and im starting to run out of hair to pull to solve this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: does a regular form post work? post the php://input here via base64_encode()

Answer (score 1):

You set your content type to urlencoded, but you don't make sure your post data is urlencoded. Add `encodeURIComponent()` around each post value:

```
xmlhttp.send("json="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"dir":parent.path})));
```

Comment: Create a basic HTML form and basic PHP page to `print_r($_POST)`, to see if that receives the post data. If that works then it narrows the problem to the gallery code and not PHP itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

changed "Accept" from "*/*" to "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" and now it works!